# Delete all files from git repository using Sourcetree

Tags: github, sourcetree

The goal is to delete all file from my git repository: I want to remove all files from my git repository and I will update new code at the Repository.

How would I do that, knowing I am using `sourcetree` windows app?

Comment: Were those files already added to the index (ready to be committed), or just created/modified without having ever been added to the repo?

Comment: VonC i want to remove all files from my git repository and i will update new code at the Repository. is that better or i have to create new fresh repository .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to remove all files from my git repository and i will update new code at the Repository.
>   Is that better or I have to create new fresh repository

It is easier to, on the GitHub website:

- rename the current repo
- re-create a brand new repo (reusing the same name as the one you just renamed, if you want)
- clone that new repo
- add your data in it, commit and push

Comment: Problem was i am new to Git, i am using source tree, i have contributors for my repository, that is missing.

Comment: @MohammadFareed Sure: you can also create a new repo with a different name, leaving your current one untouched. The idea remains to reset your content using a new empty repo.